# Turn on Webcam Device with Command

Tags: usb, command, power-management, camera

I have a problem about using webcam from terminal.  My notebook is MSI GE60 2PC Apache, and my OS is Debian 8 Jessie.

When I press FN+F6, my webcam turns on and I can use webcam with cheese application. If I press FN+F6 again, webcam turns off and I can't use webcam, there is a message "No device found". I want to control webcam with python code or bash code, I don't want to press FN+F6. How can I do?

These took my attention in syslog,

1. "XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BisonCam, NB Pro" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)"
2. "config/udev: Adding input device BisonCam, NB Pro (/dev/input/event17)"

Here, output of my syslog, when I press FN+F6:

```
kernel: [34628.327642] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
kernel: [34628.462468] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0248
kernel: [34628.462471] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=6, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: [34628.462472] usb 1-1.4: Product: BisonCam, NB Pro
kernel: [34628.464910] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device BisonCam, NB Pro (5986:0248)
mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
kernel: [34628.468993] input: BisonCam, NB Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input24
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device BisonCam, NB Pro (/dev/input/event17)
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) BisonCam, NB Pro: Applying InputClpass "evdev keyboard catchall"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'BisonCam, NB Pro'
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) BisonCam, NB Pro: always reports core events
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) evdev: BisonCam, NB Pro: Device: "/dev/input/event17"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (--) evdev: BisonCam, NB Pro: Vendor 0x5986 Product 0x248
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (--) evdev: BisonCam, NB Pro: Found keys
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (II) evdev: BisonCam, NB Pro: Configuring as keyboard
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input24/event17"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BisonCam, NB Pro" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "tr"
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: > Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: >                   Ignoring extra symbols
gdm-Xorg-:0[1092]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

Here, my "xev" output when I press "FN+F6":

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0xa8, subw 0x0, time 3880173, (803,239), root:(890,391),
    state 0x10, keycode 220 (keysym 0x1008ff8f, XF86WebCam), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0xa8, subw 0x0, time 3880280, (803,239), root:(890,391),
    state 0x10, keycode 220 (keysym 0x1008ff8f, XF86WebCam), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

With `acpi_listen`, there is no output for this FN-Combinations. Some others, like brightness, do produce output though.

Comment: It's likely that the embedded controller (EC) of your Notebook powers the camera on and off when you press `Fn+F6`. If you can't get the keyboard event with `xev` or `evtest`, try `acpi_listen`. Interacting with the EC is difficult, as it's proprietary, and not open, so quite possibly you won't be able to control it from a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem. My goal was open webcam at the beginning.

I found how works FN+F6 for me. This key is hardware related for switching on/off device. I tested it these steps:

1. I pressed FN+F6 and turned on webcam.
2. Restart computer.
3. Try open webcam and yes, webcam opened.

Finally, I wrote a bash script and this script run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to control webcam with python code or bash code, I don't want to press FN+F6. How can I do?

You can use the `webcam` command :

```
sudo apt install webcam 
webcam
```

The `xawtv` command :

```
sudo apt install xawtv
xawtv
```

The `motion` command:

```
sudo apt-get install motion
motion
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I tried all of them, but they aren't solution. I couldn't.

Comment: @FarukÜNAL please run `modprobe gspca_main` as root then run `webcam`

Comment: I run these code but there are mesagges: `vid-open: failed: libv4l
no grabber device available`. Also, I tried `modprobe ehci-pci'.